# webRTC peer connections can not make through a peer as server

Tags: p2p, webrtc

Friends,

I create a peer as server 'Peer S', then the 1st new peer 'Peer A' will join the server 'Peer S' by socket channel, the peer connection is created successfully, then 2nd peer 'Peer B' join the server like 'Peer A' does, successful too, then I want to create peer to peer connection between Peer A with Peer B through Peer S, the problem happens here:

the order is :

Peer A createOffer and setLocalDesc then send offer to Peer S, then Peer S forward offer to Peer B.

After Peer B receive offer, setRemoteDesc, then send 'Peer A can send candidates now', Peer S forward this msg to Peer A.

Peer A send 'Peer A candidates' to Peer S, then forward to Peer B, Peer B addIceCandidate

After Peer A candidates send complete, Peer B createAnswer and setLocalDesc, then Peer S will forward this answer to Peer A.

Peer A setRemoteDesc, send 'Peer B can send candidates now', then Peer S forward to Peer B.

Peer B send 'Peer B candidates', Peer S forward to Peer A, Peer A addIceCandidate.

This is the whole process, but after complete above process, the dataChannel is not created between Peer A with Peer B, the peer ice state of Peer A is 'new' or 'gathering', so does Peer B, ice state is never 'completed'.

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks!

Rosone